# How to prevent a class from inserting data in a hashmap that was declared in a different class?

Tags: java, hashmap

I was asked this question in one of the recent interviews and I am still looking for an answer.

"How to prevent a class from inserting data in a hashmap that was declared in a different class?"

To explain further - The question said that the visibility should be there even outside the class but everytime the user calls "hashmap.put("a","sss"); from outside the class - it should throw a run time exception.

Comment: Don't let that class see the HashMap?

Comment: You mean like `Collections.unmodifiableMap` does, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: The question said that the visibility should be there even outside the class but everytime  the user calls "hashmap.put("a","sss"); from outside the class - it should throw a run time exception.

Comment: Shouldn't you have written that in your original question?

Comment: Yes I should have. Thanks. Edited the question now. Hope its better to understand now.

Comment: You can declare the Map as private so that only members of that class can access it (Although there is exception to this http://www.vinaysingh.info/accessing-private-members/).

Comment: I think if I am ever asked an interview question like this, I will ask for a realistic work environment in which to answer, meaning that I have a browser with access to the Web and can Google "immutable hashmap" (which is not quite what I want, but the top pages it returns cross-reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html?is-external=true#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29 ).

Answer (score 1):

This is part of good encapsulation, protecting the inner workings of your class from others.

Make sure the `Map` field is private and whenever you return the map from your object so that others can see it make sure you wrap it in a [Collections.unmodifiableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29).

```
class X {

   private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

   public Map<String, String> getMap() {
      return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
   }
}
```

Comment: But if I make map as 'private', would that not make it invisible from outside the class? The question said that the Map should be accessible from outside as well.

Comment: @ShreyanshShiwam I've added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadoc for `Collections.unmodifiableMap`

> `public static <K,V> Map<K,V> unmodifiableMap(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)`
>
> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified map. This method
> allows modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal
> maps. Query operations on the returned map "read through" to the
> specified map, and attempts to modify the returned map, whether direct
> or via its collection views, result in an
> UnsupportedOperationException.

So you can have an ordinary map in the class that created it, and expose an unmodifiable view of it.